# How to change button text language on protable filters in Ant Design Pro

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I have a pro-table in ant design in which I[image] want to apply filtering. However, the action buttons on the filters are always in Chinese as shown in the attached image. I want to change them to English. I would really appreciate any help.

Here is my code snippet:

```
const columns:ProColumns<GithubIssueItem>[]=[
       {      
        dataIndex: 'condition',
        title: 'Condition',
        ellipsis: true,
        // valueType: "select",
        filters: true,
        onFilter: true,
        valueEnum: {
          all: { text: "Okay", status: "Default" },
          open: {
            text: "unresolved",
            status: "Error",
          },
          closed: {
            text: "resolved",
            status: "Success",
            disabled: true,
          },
          processing: {
            text: "solving",
            status: "Processing",
          },
        },
      },
    ...
   ]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This looks like a problem with your localizations. Make sure that your current locale is set to 'en-US' (I assume that thats your language key as the rest of the ui seems to be in english).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution (other solutions didn't work for me):

```
import { ConfigProvider } from '@ant-design/pro-provider';

<ConfigProvider
  value={{
    intl: enUSIntl,
  }}
>
  <ProTable />
</ConfigProvider>;
```

It can be declared in the main file (app.js for example) and it will change the language of all the pro components. [Found here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro/issues/9219#issuecomment-996663963).

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution for ProTable locale of ant design pro.
In your App.js:

1. Import config locale of ant:

```
import {
  ConfigProvider
} from "antd";

import moment from "moment";

import enUS from "antd/lib/locale-provider/en_US";
```

2. Wrap the ConfigProvider outside <YOUR_CONTENT/>:

```
        <ConfigProvider locale={enUS}>
         <YOUR_CONTENT/>
       </ConfigProvide>
```

3. Add moment outside your App.js:

```
moment.locale("en");
```

The config provider of Ant Pro will auto change the Chinese language in every component you use of Ant Design Pro.

Comment: this doesn't work.

Comment: @DinhMinhLuu Show me your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the ConfigProvider and the locale from antd

```
import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd'
import enUS from 'antd/es/locale/en_US';

return (
  <ConfigProvider locale={enUS}>
    <App />
  </ConfigProvider>
);
```